# "Error: Cannot find module 'handler'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried to deploy a simple function using AWS Lambda. However, I got this error even though I set the handler correctly.
P/s: I did not use the serverless.yml nor CLI. I deployed it using AWS Lambda interface.

**Lambda Handler**: functions/fetchNest/handler.fetch

**Error:**

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'handler'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'handler'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:951:17)",
        "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:976:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"
    ]
```

**handler.js**

```
module.exports.fetch = async event => {

  // Get SSM creds.
```

**folder structure**

[image]

Comment: Start with the sample code provided by Amazon and build from there. I bet your handler should be something much simpler like "handler" instead of what you're using

Comment: It should be judging by the code I provide which it didn't work. Not that passing the code from Amazon would make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Compress FileName` in MacOS, else you'll end up zipping your files with chaos. Use command `zip` instead. For example:

`zip testFile.zip index.js node_modules utils`

This will create the zip file contains all your required sub files and folders. After that you can config your Handler in Lambda like this

`testFile/index.hander`